# Saxon XMLBeans Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, saxon, xmlbeans

We recently updated our Tomcat web service. The only things we really updated were that we updated XMLBeans to version 2.4 and Saxon to version 9.

Running it Netbeans and eclipse, our project now works fine, but when trying to deploy to tomcat we get the following.

We tried updating JAXEN to version 1.1.1 but no joy.

Any ideas?

The error we get in deployment is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dom4j-core,jdom,xml-apis,xerces,junit-Extension-Name
        at java.util.jar.Attributes$Name.(Attributes.java:440)
        at java.util.jar.Attributes.getValue(Attributes.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.ManifestResource.getRequiredExtensions(ManifestResource.java:186)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.ManifestResource.processManifest(ManifestResource.java:155)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.ManifestResource.(ManifestResource.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.validateApplication(ExtensionValidator.java:186)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:626)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:511)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1220)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DynamicMetaDataImpl.invoke(DynamicMetaDataImpl.java:213)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MetaDataImpl.invoke(MetaDataImpl.java:220)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:815)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:784)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1458)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:820)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:348)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:196)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:263)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:584)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is being caused by a JAR file whose MANIFEST.MF file contains a value for the `Extension-List` attribute that Tomcat doesn't like.  Tomcat expects this attribute's value to be a space-separated list of extension names (see the [ManifestResource source](http://kickjava.com/src/org/apache/catalina/util/ManifestResource.java.htm)), but it appears one of your JARs has the comma-separated list `dom4j-core,jdom,xml-apis,xerces,junit` instead.  There are no spaces in this list, so Tomcat thinks it's all one big extension name.

Extension names are also used to prefix names of further attributes within the manifest.  For example, here's part of a valid manifest:

```
Extension-List: ant qdox commons-attributes-api javadoc
ant-Extension-Name: ant
ant-Implementation-Version: 1.5
ant-Implementation-URL: http://www.ibiblio.org/maven/ant/jars/ant-1.5.
 jar
qdox-Extension-Name: qdox
qdox-Implementation-Version: 1.5
```

Attribute names can only contain letters, numbers, hyphens and underscores, and so extension names must also follow the same rules.  An extension name with a comma in it is clearly not valid, and this is why you are getting the exception above.

I've had a look at the official [JAR file specification](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html), but that appears not to state how these extension names should be delimited.

I can't say which JAR has this comma-separated `Extension-List` attribute in its manifest.  However, I would check the JAR files within the latest versions of XMLBeans and Saxon first.  If your project worked before the upgrade, then it's likely that the problem has been caused by something that has changed recently.

The fix is of course to edit the offending manifest file to use spaces instead of commas in its `Extension-List` attribute.

Good luck!

Comment: We ended up taking out the jars that we werent using, and this fixed it, therefor it was one of the saxon9 jars besides saxon9.jar and saxon9-dom.jar

Comment: Odd... I've just downloaded the latest Saxon jars and none of them seem to have the attribute that would cause this problem.  Nonetheless, I'm glad to see you've fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting jaxen-1.1-beta-2.jar in the lib directory of the application and replace it with jaxen-1.1.6.jar worked for me. jaxen-1.1-beta-2.jar has the Extension list dom4j-core,jdom,xml-apis,xerces,junit in its MANIFEST.MF file.
Reference: https://www.twblogs.net/a/5b8833f42b71775d1cdaf884