# IllegalArgumentException while upgrading application from Weblogic 8.1 to Weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: java, deployment, weblogic11g

I am in the process of upgrading a legacy java application from Weblogic 8.1 to Weblogic 10.3.6 (also the java version from 1.4 to 1.6). I built the weblogic full client jar file [as per these instructions](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13717_06/jarbuilder.htm) and added it to the classpath.

When I deploy the application in Weblogic 10.3.6 it fails with the following error...

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javacc,ant,commons-collections,log4j,junit-Extension-Name
        at java.util.jar.Attributes$Name.<init>(Attributes.java:447)
        at java.util.jar.Attributes.getValue(Attributes.java:99)
        at weblogic.application.library.LibraryReferenceFactory.getOptPackReference(LibraryReferenceFactory.java:135)
        at weblogic.application.internal.OptionalPackageProviderImpl.getOptionalPackages(OptionalPackageProviderImpl.java:44)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ClassFinderUtils.getOptionalPackages(ClassFinderUtils.java:145)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ClassFinderUtils.getManifestClassPath(ClassFinderUtils.java:126)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ClassFinderUtils.getManifestFinder(ClassFinderUtils.java:98)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ClassFinderUtils.getManifestFinder(ClassFinderUtils.java:79)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.JarClassFinder.<init>(JarClassFinder.java:41)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.JarClassFinder.<init>(JarClassFinder.java:30)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ClasspathClassFinder2.getClassFinder(ClasspathClassFinder2.java:87)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ClasspathClassFinder2.setClasspath(ClasspathClassFinder2.java:80)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ClasspathClassFinder2.<init>(ClasspathClassFinder2.java:54)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ClasspathClassFinder2.<init>(ClasspathClassFinder2.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.io.ExplodedJar.buildClasspathFinder(ExplodedJar.java:141)
        at weblogic.application.io.ExplodedJar.getClassFinder(ExplodedJar.java:87)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ArchivedWar.getClassFinder(ArchivedWar.java:72)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.War.init(War.java:246)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.War.<init>(War.java:217)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.processDocroot(WebAppServletContext.java:2785)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.setDocroot(WebAppServletContext.java:2662)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:414)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:494)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.loadWebApp(HttpServer.java:418)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.registerWebApp(WebAppModule.java:976)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:384)
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're upgrading to java 1.6? Why? It's no longer supported (unless you have extended support from Oracle). Upgrade to 1.8. -- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html

Comment: @Asaph 1.8 is not supported by Weblogic 11g and we have to use use 11g at the moment. [JRE 8 compatibility with weblogic 10.3.6 (11g)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513660/jre-8-compatibility-with-weblogic-10-3-6-11g)

Comment: right, do not use 1.8 in 10.3.x

Comment: have you bundled wlfullclient into your application and then deployed it ?

Comment: @devwebcl yes I have

Answer (score 1):

[The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854711/saxon-xmlbeans-tomcat) helped me solve my problem.

One of the jar files that was used had comma separated string against the `Extension-List` property in the MANIFEST.MF file. Updated the jar file with the later release which did not have the comma-separated string.

Posting this solution as an answer to help anyone who encounters this problem.

Comment: it is good to see that you solved the problem, however it is not good to bundle wlfullclient into your application because all those are libraries are already in WLS. (it is redundant)

Comment: Yeah I did notice that @devwebcl so I removed them from the application package. Thanks.